# Filtrar un aggregation en mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sql, filtro

Necesito aplicar un filtro tipo $match (aunque me vale cualquier forma) para que al crear el aggregate no tenga en cuenta los valores "Undefined" de la columna "cast":

```
db.getCollection("actors").find({})

db.actors.aggregate([

{$group:  { _id:"$cast", Peliculas: {$sum:1}},
},
{$sort: {Peliculas: -1 }},
{$limit: 2}
])
```

[image: Code]

Actualmente solo he conseguido agregar y ordenar los resultados, pero necesito que desaparezca el _id Undefined para que me muestre solo los actores reales.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: you are in stack overflow in Spanish so please translate your question.

Comment: Hola. Disculpad, he tenido una confusión pensando que publicaba en el global. Lo que necesito es saber como aplicar un filtro para hacer que desaparezcan todos los valores Undefined y me muestre como primer resultado Harold Lloyd. Estoy haciendo el recuento de número de peliculas por actor, y entonces me aparece el actor "Undefined" como el que tiene más peliculas.

Answer (score 2):

Resuelto añadiendo esta línea al código:

```
 {$match: {cast:{$ne:"Undefined"}}},
```

Y quedaría algo como:

```
db.actors.aggregate([
    {$match: {cast:{$ne:"Undefined"}}},
    {$group : {_id: "$cast", total : {$sum: 1 }}},
    {$sort:{total:-1}},
    {$limit:5}])
```

[image: Studio 3T]

Gracias.